# Jquery clone and appendto for parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 radio buttons which open up the individual divs. All the 3 divs has input boxes which can be added by clicking on the add button next to the input box.

Problem in this now is,

Input boxes should be adding only  in the respective radio checked div but now it is aplying for all the 3 div input boxes. If you check on the any one radio button and click on the add button next to input, add few input boxes then go to another radio button and you can see the same action there also which should not actually right.

Here is the code and the fiddle

```
$filtr = $('.filtr');

        $filtr.on('click', '.add', function(){
            $(this).closest('.loop').clone().appendTo( $('.test') );
        });

        $filtr.on('click', '.del', function(){
           $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
        });

        $('#1lev, #2lev, #3lev').hide();
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/)**

Comment: Could you please phrase an exact question for your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/2/

I changed this:

```
$filtr.on('click', '.add', function(){
    $(this).closest('.loop').clone().appendTo( $('.test') );
});
```

to this:

```
$filtr.on('click', '.add', function(){
    $(this).closest('.loop').clone().appendTo( $(this).closest('.test') );
});
```

hope it helps

---

**EDIT**

radio buttons improvement: check here -> http://jsfiddle.net/VMBtC/3/

**JS**

```
$(":radio").click(function(){
     $(".test").hide();
     var show = $(this).attr("data-show");
     $("#"+show).show(300)
});
```

**HTML**

```
<label><input name="1 Level" type="radio" value="0" data-show="1lev" />1 Level</label>
<label><input name="1 Level" type="radio" value="1" data-show="2lev" />2 Level</label>
<label><input name="1 Level" type="radio" value="2" data-show="3lev" />3 Level</label>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. :) One more thing, Is there any short way to write script for radio button check? Coz currently my code for that is quite manual so

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).closest('.loop').clone().appendTo( $(this).closest('.test') );`, otherwise you'd be adding to *every* `.test` element.